# How do I get "full-screen" routine editing in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: function, phpmyadmin

I am migrating from a Debian 8 to Debian 11 server, and moving from phpMyAdmin 4.2.12 to 5.0.4.  The older version of phpMyAdmin has a great layout for working with stored routines.  They display organically on the page and use the full real estate available, like the way every other database object is edited.

Version 5.0.4, however, always opens up routines in a popup that is inconveniently sized and placed and has to be moved and resized each time to be able to do anything with it:

Is there any setting or method to get the old behaviour back?  I don't want the popup.

The old way routines are displayed and edited is shown below:

[image: phpMyAdmin 4.2.12 Routines Editor]

Here is version 5.0.4:

[image: phpMyAdmin 5.0.4 with "Popup" Routines Editor]

I would really love to get the old behaviour back.  For those who work with a lot of stored procedures and functions, resizing a popup every time is awful.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by accident this morning but for all my clicking can't recreate it. Really wish this had been answered!